# Cursor$DefaultCursor cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean?

Tags: java, rethinkdb

Getting the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.rethinkdb.net.Cursor$DefaultCursor cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean`

```
// Login Validation
if (r.db("APSCI").table("BankAccounts").filter(row ->
   row.g("username").eq(username).and(row.g("password").eq(password))).run(conn)) {
   System.out.print("Welcome /n (username)");
}
else {
    System.out.print("No User Was Found!");
}
```

I'm trying to check if the username & password are valid against the user input from the scanner.

Comment: I'd suggest you research how to save passwords in general. Hint: you don't, you just save a (salted) hash of the password, so that anybody stealing your user database doesn't have all your passwords. With that, look into libraries that handle these details for you (cryptography is hard). For example, Spring Security has such a library.

Comment: @Robert Thank You! I figured I would first get it working then go into hashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how the Java connector works, but you may find `.coerceTo` helpful:

```
r.db('APSCI').table('BankAccounts')
.getAll(username, {index: 'username'})
.filter({password: password})
.coerceTo('BOOL')
```

The result is `true` if the sequence is not empty, `false` otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, Alright! Do you know how I would add this in as if it equaled the Username & Password! It gets the user input from Scanners for both the username and the password. @Stock Overflaw

Comment: Along with this, when trying to put this into an if Statement, I keep having tons of issues. If you would be willing to edit/change you're response/explain how to add it into an if statement that would be amazing. Also, in Java I am getting a number of unclosed characters. Do you have Discord as a means for 1 on 1? If you wouldn't mind please add me - Austin#6574

Comment: if (r.db("APSCI").table("BankAccounts").filter(row ->
                         row.g("username").eq(username).and(row.g("password").eq(password))).coerceTo("BOOL").run(conn)){
                         System.out.print("Welcome /n (username)");
                      } Ended up being the code BTW

Comment: Sorry I wasn't connected at that time, however it seems you found a way to go. As a side note, I strongly advise to avoid using `.filter` directly on a table: `.filter` does not use indexes, thus making it slow and resource-consuming. In the answer I posted, I used the index-based `.getAll` to reduce the set on which the `.filter` would apply, but this assumes you created an index on the table using `.indexCreate('username')`.